# Optimizing queries used in PXSelect

Tags: acumatica

I've got this code which makes my grid timeout when trying to execute it from one particular user in Acumatica on an Azure S2 MSSQL DB.

It doesnt timeout with an Azure S3 MSSQL DB.

```
  public class CTInquiriesCollecteur : PXGraph<CTInquiriesCollecteur>
    {
        [PXFilterable]
        public PXSelectJoin<POOrder,
            InnerJoin<Contact,
                On<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<POOrder.vendorID>>,
               InnerJoin<CROpportunity,
                   On<CROpportunity.opportunityID, Equal<POOrderExt.usrBSD>,Or<CROpportunityExt.usrEBDR,Equal<POOrderExt.usrBRD>>>>>,
            Where<Contact.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>> poCollecteur;
    }
}
```

It works with other users (but they have less records returned than the one which crash it)
When I try the query using my SQL Manager it works fine and returns the 1743 lines I want :

```
Select * from POOrder inner Join Contact on Contact.BaCcountID=POOrder.VendorID Inner join CROpportunity
 on ( CROpportunity.opportunityID=POOrder.usrBSD or CROpportunity.opportunityID=POOrder.UsrBRD) 
 Where poorder.CompanyID=5 and Contact.companyID=5 and CROpportunity.CompanyID=5 and Contact.contactID=12688
```

This query returning all the lines (not filtering on the contactID) works fine (yet it returns WAY more lines than the one filtering on the contactID) :

```
 public class CTInquiriesEmployes : PXGraph<CTInquiriesEmployes>
    {
        [PXFilterable]
        public PXSelectReadonly2<POOrder, InnerJoin<CROpportunity, 
            On<CROpportunity.opportunityID, Equal<POOrderExt.usrBSD>,Or<CROpportunityExt.usrEBDR,Equal<POOrderExt.usrBRD>>>>> po;
    }
```

Do you have any hints on how I could optimize this query so I dont need a S3 DB on Azure and I can stick with a S2 ?

Edit :

I looked at the query plan and it seems that this is the request generated by the code sample and which timesout my db :

```
(@P0 uniqueidentifier,@P1 char(1))SELECT TOP (20) [POOrder].[BranchID], [POOrder].[OrderType], [POOrder].[OrderNbr], [POOrder].[VendorID], [POOrder].[VendorLocationID], [POOrder].[OrderDate], [POOrder].[ExpectedDate], [POOrder].[ExpirationDate], [POOrder].[Status], [POOrder].[Hold], [POOrder].[Approved], [POOrder].[Cancelled], [POOrder].[Receipt], [POOrder].[IsTaxValid], [POOrder].[IsOpenTaxValid], [POOrder].[NoteID], (SELECT TOP (1) [Note_s18].[NoteText] FROM [dbo].[Note] [Note_s18] WHERE [Note_s18].CompanyID IN (1, 5) AND 2 = SUBSTRING([Note_s18].CompanyMask, 2, 1) & 2 AND [Note_s18].[NoteId] = [POOrder].[NoteID]), (SELECT TOP (1) COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[NoteDoc] [NoteDoc_s20] WHERE [NoteDoc_s20].CompanyID IN (1, 5) AND 2 = SUBSTRING([NoteDoc_s20].CompanyMask, 2, 1) & 2 AND [NoteDoc_s20].[NoteId] = [POOrder].[NoteID]), NULL, [POOrder].[CuryID], [POOrder].[CuryInfoID], [POOrder].[LineCntr], [POOrder].[VendorRefNbr], [POOrder].[CuryOrderTotal], [POOrder].[OrderTotal], [POOrder].[CuryControlTotal], [POOrder].[ControlTotal], [POOrder].[OrderQty], [POOrder].[CuryLineTotal], [POOrder].[LineTotal], [POOrder].[DiscTot], [POOrder].[CuryDiscTot], [POOrder].[CuryTaxTotal], [POOrder].[TaxTotal], [POOrder].[CuryVatExemptTotal], [POOrder].[VatExemptTotal], [POOrder].[CuryVatTaxableTotal], [POOrder].[VatTaxableTotal], [POOrder].[TaxZoneID], [POOrder].[TermsID], [POOrder].[RemitAddressID], [POOrder].[RemitContactID], [POOrder].[SOOrderType], [POOrder].[SOOrderNbr], [POOrder].[BLType], [POOrder].[BLOrderNbr], [POOrder].[RQReqNbr], [POOrder].[OrderDesc], [POOrder].[tstamp], [POOrder].[CreatedByID], [POOrder].[CreatedByScreenID], [POOrder].[CreatedDateTime], [POOrder].[LastModifiedByID], [POOrder].[LastModifiedByScreenID], [POOrder].[LastModifiedDateTime], [POOrder].[ShipDestType], [POOrder].[SiteID], [POOrder].[ShipToBAccountID], [POOrder].[ShipToLocationID], [POOrder].[ShipAddressID], [POOrder].[ShipContactID], [POOrder].[CuryOpenOrderTotal], [POOrder].[OpenOrderTotal], [POOrder].[CuryOpenLineTotal], [POOrder].[OpenLineTotal], [POOrder].[CuryOpenTaxTotal], [POOrder].[OpenTaxTotal], [POOrder].[OpenOrderQty], [POOrder].[EmployeeID], [POOrder].[OwnerWorkgroupID], [POOrder].[DontPrint], [POOrder].[Printed], [POOrder].[DontEmail], [POOrder].[Emailed], [POOrder].[FOBPoint], [POOrder].[ShipVia], [POOrder].[OrderWeight], [POOrder].[OrderVolume], [POOrder].[PrepaymentDocType], [POOrder].[PrepaymentRefNbr], [POOrder].[UsrObservation], [POOrder].[UsrBSD], [POOrder].[UsrBRD], [POOrder].[UsrTypePO], [POOrder].[UsrPAV], [POOrder].[UsrLicenseExport], [POOrder].[UsrCodeMouvement], [POOrder].[UsrNumeroContainer], [POOrder].[UsrDepartBateauDate], [POOrder].[UsrFiliere], [Contact].[DisplayName], [Contact].[ContactID], [Contact].[RevisionID], [Contact].[DefAddressID], [Contact].[Title], [Contact].[FirstName], [Contact].[MidName], [Contact].[LastName], [Contact].[Salutation], [Contact].[BAccountID], [Contact].[FullName], [Contact].[ParentBAccountID], [Contact].[EMail], [Contact].[WebSite], [Contact].[Fax], [Contact].[FaxType], [Contact].[Phone1], [Contact].[Phone1Type], [Contact].[Phone2], [Contact].[Phone2Type], [Contact].[Phone3], [Contact].[Phone3Type], [Contact].[DateOfBirth], [Contact].[NoteID], NULL, NULL, NULL, [Contact].[IsActive], [Contact].[NoFax], [Contact].[NoMail], [Contact].[NoMarketing], [Contact].[NoCall], [Contact].[NoEMail], [Contact].[NoMassMail], [Contact].[Gender], [Contact].[MaritalStatus], [Contact].[Anniversary], [Contact].[Spouse], [Contact].[Img], [Contact].[Synchronize], [Contact].[ContactType], CASE WHEN  ( [Contact].[ContactType] = 'AP') THEN  -10 WHEN  ( ( [Contact].[ContactType] = 'SP')) THEN  -5 WHEN  ( ( [Contact].[ContactType] = 'EP')) THEN  -1 WHEN  ( ( [Contact].[ContactType] = 'PN')) THEN  0 WHEN  ( ( [Contact].[ContactType] = 'LD')) THEN  10 END, [Contact].[DuplicateStatus], CASE WHEN  ( [Contact].[DuplicateStatus] = 'PD' AND 1 = 0 ) THEN  CONVERT(BIT, 1) ELSE  CONVERT(BIT, 0) END, [Contact].[MajorStatus], [Contact].[Status], [Contact].[Resolution], [Contact].[AssignDate], [Contact].[QualificationDate], [Contact].[ClassID], [Contact].[Source], [Contact].[WorkgroupID], [Contact].[OwnerID], [Contact].[UserID], [Contact].[CampaignID], [Contact].[Method], [Contact].[IsConvertable], [Contact].[GrammValidationDateTime], [Contact].[ConvertedBy], [Contact].[CreatedByID], [Contact].[CreatedByScreenID], [Contact].[CreatedDateTime], [Contact].[LastModifiedByID], [Contact].[LastModifiedByScreenID], [Contact].[LastModifiedDateTime], '"' +  ( [Contact].[DisplayName] +  ( '"' +  ( ' ' +  ( '(' +  ( [Contact].[EMail] +  ')'))))), [Contact].[ExtRefNbr], [Contact].[tstamp], [Contact].[DeletedDatabaseRecord], [CROpportunity].[OpportunityNumber], [CROpportunity].[OpportunityID], [CROpportunity].[BranchID], [CROpportunity].[OpportunityAddressID], [CROpportunity].[OpportunityContactID], [CROpportunity].[AllowOverrideContactAddress], [CROpportunity].[BAccountID], [CROpportunity].[LocationID], [CROpportunity].[ContactID], [CROpportunity].[ConvertedLeadID], [CROpportunity].[CROpportunityClassID], [CROpportunity].[OpportunityName], [CROpportunity].[Description], [CROpportunity].[ParentBAccountID], [CROpportunity].[ProjectID], [CROpportunity].[CloseDate], [CROpportunity].[StageID], [CROpportunity].[StageChangedDate], [CROpportunity].[CampaignSourceID], [CROpportunity].[MajorStatus], [CROpportunity].[Status], [CROpportunity].[Resolution], [CROpportunity].[AssignDate], [CROpportunity].[ClosingDate], [CROpportunity].[WorkgroupID], [CROpportunity].[OwnerID], [CROpportunity].[CuryID], [CROpportunity].[CuryInfoID], [CROpportunity].[LineTotal], [CROpportunity].[CuryLineTotal], [CROpportunity].[IsTaxValid], [CROpportunity].[TaxTotal], [CROpportunity].[CuryTaxTotal], [CROpportunity].[ManualTotalEntry], [CROpportunity].[Amount], CASE WHEN  ( [CROpportunity].[ManualTotalEntry] = CONVERT(BIT, 1)) THEN  [CROpportunity].[Amount] ELSE  [CROpportunity].[LineTotal] END, [CROpportunity].[CuryAmount], [CROpportunity].[DiscTot], [CROpportunity].[CuryDiscTot], [CROpportunity].[ProductsAmount], [CROpportunity].[CuryProductsAmount], [CROpportunity].[CuryVatExemptTotal], [CROpportunity].[VatExemptTotal], [CROpportunity].[CuryVatTaxableTotal], [CROpportunity].[VatTaxableTotal], [CROpportunity].[TaxZoneID], [CROpportunity].[ARRefNbr], [CROpportunity].[OrderType], [CROpportunity].[OrderNbr], [CROpportunity].[NoteID], NULL, NULL, NULL, (SELECT TOP (1) CASE WHEN  ( [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] IS NOT NULL AND [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] IS NULL) THEN  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] WHEN  ( [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] IS NOT NULL AND [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] IS NULL) THEN  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] WHEN  ( [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] > [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate]) THEN  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] ELSE  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] END FROM [CRActivityStatistics] [CRActivityStatistics_s217] WHERE [CRActivityStatistics_s217].CompanyID = 5 AND [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[NoteID] = [CROpportunity].[NoteID] ORDER BY CASE WHEN  ( [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] IS NOT NULL AND [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] IS NULL) THEN  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] WHEN  ( [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] IS NOT NULL AND [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] IS NULL) THEN  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] WHEN  ( [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] > [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate]) THEN  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastIncomingActivityDate] ELSE  [CRActivityStatistics_s217].[LastOutgoingActivityDate] END), [CROpportunity].[Source], [CROpportunity].[tstamp], [CROpportunity].[CreatedByScreenID], [CROpportunity].[CreatedByID], [CROpportunity].[CreatedDateTime], [CROpportunity].[LastModifiedByID], [CROpportunity].[LastModifiedByScreenID], [CROpportunity].[LastModifiedDateTime], [CROpportunity].[ProductCntr], [CROpportunity].[UsrObservation], [CROpportunity].[UsrDateCollecte], [CROpportunity].[UsrDateReprise], [CROpportunity].[UsrCollecteur], [CROpportunity].[UsrTraiteur], [CROpportunity].[UsrEBDR], CASE WHEN [POOrder].[OrderType] = 'RO' THEN 'Normal' END AS orderby_case_s232
FROM [POOrder] [POOrder]
INNER JOIN [Contact] [Contact] ON [Contact].CompanyID = 5 AND [Contact].[DeletedDatabaseRecord] = 0 AND [Contact].[BAccountID] = [POOrder].[VendorID]
INNER JOIN [CROpportunity] [CROpportunity] ON [CROpportunity].CompanyID = 5 AND ([CROpportunity].BranchID IS NULL OR [CROpportunity].BranchID = 25) AND ([CROpportunity].[OpportunityID] = [POOrder].[UsrBSD] OR [CROpportunity].[UsrEBDR] = [POOrder].[UsrBRD])
WHERE [POOrder].CompanyID = 5 AND ([POOrder].BranchID IS NULL OR [POOrder].BranchID = 25) AND [Contact].[UserID] = @P0 AND [POOrder].[Status] = @P1
ORDER BY [POOrder].[OrderNbr], orderby_case_s232 OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)
```

Edit 2 :

Looking into the DB for table POOrder I already have a few indexes, one on the primary keys, one on Vendor, one on NoteID and this strange one :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_POOrder_35EBA31CDEA74D944FD7F833E2CF9116] ON [dbo].[POOrder]
(
    [BranchID] ASC,
    [CompanyID] ASC,
    [UsrBSD] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Approved],
    [BLOrderNbr],
    [BLType],
    [Cancelled],
    [ControlTotal],
    [CreatedByID],
    [CreatedByScreenID],
    [CreatedDateTime],
    [CuryControlTotal],
    [CuryDiscTot],
    [CuryID],
    [CuryInfoID],
    [CuryLineTotal],
    [CuryOpenLineTotal],
    [CuryOpenOrderTotal],
    [CuryOpenTaxTotal],
    [CuryOrderTotal],
    [CuryTaxTotal],
    [CuryVatExemptTotal],
    [CuryVatTaxableTotal],
    [DiscTot],
    [DontEmail],
    [DontPrint],
    [Emailed],
    [EmployeeID],
    [ExpectedDate],
    [ExpirationDate],
    [FOBPoint],
    [Hold],
    [IsOpenTaxValid],
    [IsTaxValid],
    [LastModifiedByID],
    [LastModifiedByScreenID],
    [LastModifiedDateTime],
    [LineCntr],
    [LineTotal],
    [NoteID],
    [OpenLineTotal],
    [OpenOrderQty],
    [OpenOrderTotal],
    [OpenTaxTotal],
    [OrderDate],
    [OrderDesc],
    [OrderQty],
    [OrderTotal],
    [OrderVolume],
    [OrderWeight],
    [OwnerWorkGroupID],
    [PrepaymentDocType],
    [PrepaymentRefNbr],
    [Printed],
    [Receipt],
    [RemitAddressID],
    [RemitContactID],
    [RQReqNbr],
    [ShipAddressID],
    [ShipContactID],
    [ShipDestType],
    [ShipToBAccountID],
    [ShipToLocationID],
    [ShipVia],
    [SiteID],
    [soordernbr],
    [soordertype],
    [Status],
    [TaxTotal],
    [TaxZoneID],
    [TermsID],
    [tstamp],
    [UsrBRD],
    [UsrCodeMouvement],
    [UsrDepartBateauDate],
    [UsrFiliere],
    [UsrLicenseExport],
    [UsrNumeroContainer],
    [UsrObservation],
    [UsrPAV],
    [UsrTypePO],
    [VatExemptTotal],
    [VatTaxableTotal],
    [VendorID],
    [VendorLocationID],
    [VendorRefNbr]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

I think it was an automatically generated index (maybe by Azure? I can't find it in the automatic tuning history), but I dont know why and If I should keep it and just index on UsrBSD and UserBRD ?

Comment: Do you have paging enabled in the PXGrid in UI to reduce the number of records requested from SQL server? With deactivated paging, PXGrid always requests all records from the database. Another suggestion is to analyze the execution plan for your first query in SSMS and, if needed, create one or several indexes to speed up this query execution.

Comment: @RuslanDev Thanks for your answer, how do you use paging ? I've been looking in the Acumatica Framework guide and I couldnt find where the paging activation or disactivation is mentionned. Regards

Comment: @Maxime have you looked at the query plan? I think you may need to add an index on the usrBSD field and another one on usrEBDR for best performance - in all cases, you should review the generated plan... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-query-performance

Comment: @RuslanDev I did take a look at the query plan, but I couldnt make any good use of it, Azure doesnt give me much advices about creating indexes despite the customer using this base for the last two years.

Answer (score 1):

To enable pagination for PXGrid, in Aspx you should at least set its `AllowPaging` property to **True** or set the property `SkinID` to one of the skins that have `AllowPaging` set to **True** (like **PrimaryInquire**). In case there is a delegate defined for the **poCollecteur** data view, then you must also follow the approach shown below to preserve pagination and not retrieve all records from the database every time data is selected from the **poCollecteur** data view.

```
public class AccountByPeriodEnq_Extension : PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
{
    [PXFilterable]
    public PXSelectOrderBy<GLTranR,
        OrderBy<Asc<GLTranR.tranDate,
            Asc<GLTranR.refNbr,
            Asc<GLTranR.batchNbr,
            Asc<GLTranR.module,
            Asc<GLTranR.lineNbr>>>>>>> GLTranEnq;

    protected IEnumerable glTranEnq()
    {
        int startRow = PXView.StartRow;
        int totalRows = 0;

        var result = Base.GLTranEnq.View.Select(PXView.Currents,
            PXView.Parameters, PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns,
            PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters, ref startRow,
            PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRows);

        PXView.StartRow = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after checking, allowpaging is already set to true, and there's not delegate for pocollector, it's just a view to show datas, there's no logic involved. I'll give the indexes a try :).

Comment: Actually there's already an index with both these fields in the DB (and a lot of other fields, so I dont know if it's really a usefull index). (I edited my question)